Memory leak using Nvidia's NVML
In a project I'm using the nvml lib to get info about the GPU in a system. I use it to query the GPU name and GPU UUID. This happens cyclic 6 to 8 time per minute.
I noticed a small memory leak which causes a crash of my application after a few hours.
The way I am using nvml to query GPU device name is like followed:
nvmlReturn_t result = nvmlInit();

nvmlDevice_t device;
result = nvmlDeviceGetHandleByIndex(deviceNum, &device);

char nameBuffer[NVML_DEVICE_NAME_BUFFER_SIZE];
result = nvmlDeviceGetName(device, nameBuffer, NVML_DEVICE_NAME_BUFFER_SIZE);

result = nvmlShutdown();

But even if I change the code just an init and shutdown of nvml the used memory is still constantly increasing:
nvmlReturn_t result = nvmlInit();

// nvmlDevice_t device;
// result = nvmlDeviceGetHandleByIndex(deviceNum, &device);

// char nameBuffer[NVML_DEVICE_NAME_BUFFER_SIZE];
// result = nvmlDeviceGetName(device, nameBuffer, NVML_DEVICE_NAME_BUFFER_SIZE);

result = nvmlShutdown();

Am I using the API correct or is there something wrong?
Is there a known issue in the nvml lib?
Systeminfo:
OS: Windows 10
Nvidia Driver: 536.40
Cuda: 12.2

If you think you have found a bug, it would be better to report it directly to NVIDIA than post a question here. Of course, you would need to supply much more information (OS, driver version, compiler, [MCVE], etc) than you have done here.

I made a simple C file that just calls nvmlInit() and nvmlShutdown() in a loop. I see no difference in memory use between 100, 1000 or 10,000 iterations.

@Homer512 maybe it depends on driver/lib version. Which OS you used to test? I'm using windows 10.

@talonmies I agree. But for now I am not sure if I have found a bug. Maybe it is just a wrong usage by me.

I'm on linux with cuda-12.3.2 and driver 550.78. Probably a bit older than what you have

I have added information about OS, Nvidia driver and cuda version to may question. @Homer512 my cuda version and driver are a bit older than yours.

Is there a specific reason you're calling init and shutdown every time instead of just once?

Yes. It is part of a dll running as plugin in a software I don't have under control. Every call it loads a tensorrt engine from file. After loading it checks if the system's GPU is the same the engine was built with.

Further tests today seem to sho there is a issue with the nvidia driver 536.x. I will write a more detailed answer later.

Here the simple solution to the problem:
I tested with the simple c file from Homer512 from the comments (just init and shutdown nvml in a loop). Over time the test system ran  out of memory.
Then I updated the Nvidia driver to latest version (556.12). This seems to fix the issue.
